# Getting source of __("some text")

Tags: php, magento2

In the phtml of Magento (Porto theme) there are a lot of echo's that look like this:

```
<?php echo __("Don't show this popup again"); ?>
```

My problem is that when I edit the csv file that is supposed to translate those texts, nothing happends. I'm not sure if I'm editing the right file or not. But I don't think so since deleting the file and clearing Magento cache doesn't change anything.

My question: Is there a way to return the source files __("") utilizes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have an IDE like PHPStorm you can do "shift + modifier + F" to search in path to try to find the phrase. Other programs should have similar features and it can be done via CLI if needed.

Comment: Since the Helper isn't specified Magento will attempt to find that string in any loaded translation I think - however, there's a distinct possibility that **no** translation has been set up for it in which case it'll just output that string *as is*. Otherwise you're looking in `app/locale` or `app/design/frontend/{theme}/locale`

Comment: I see, it's loaded in a translation file for sure, it's working fine. I just have to add a few translations. But there are so many translation files everywere that I don't know which one. Do you know if it's possible to check the currently loaded in files?

Comment: Easiest thing to do, as @MarkusTenghamn suggested, grep the codebase - Magento is like that - Notepad++ *"Find in files"* will do the job if you're on Windows. Just noticed it's tagged *magento2* as well so the filepaths are different to Magento 1.9x for the translation files.

Comment: ... and, as Magento 2 has been made more modular, the `i18n` directories are inside the modules - and since everything is a module they're going to be all over the place : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, I found it via Atom's search function.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the source at [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Translate/Adapter.php#L39-L48).

I found it using `grep -Hr 'function __('`.